# Execution order of Timeout and Promise functions(Main Tasks and Micro Tasks)

Tags: javascript

I was browsing the html5boilerplate github and I went to see some of the interview questions and I came across this one and I don't understand why it outputs in the order it does. I assumed it would be one four two three not the output it does. Can someone explain why? sorry if it's too simplistic.

Question: What does the following code print?

```
console.log('one');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('two');
}, 0);
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('three');
})
console.log('four');
```

The output was in this order "one" "four" "three" and finally "two"

**Code Snippet**

```js
console.log('one');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('two');
}, 0);
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('three');
})
console.log('four');
```

Comment: Imho, the first two should be clear. Afterwards, promises are put into a microtask queue, which gets completed before the main event queue, that does e.g. `setTimeout` tasks.

Comment: @gforce301 considering my question covers "a specific programming problem" then I don't know how it's not appropriate for SO

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think output `one` and `four` are pretty clear. `setTimeout` is a part of **Main Task** queue  while `Promise` is of **Micro task** queue that's why **"three" and finally "two"** is printed.

**Step by Step execution is as below:**

1. When script is executed, **console.log(“one”)** is executed first.
2. When `setTimeout(…)` is encountered, runtime initiates a timer, and after 0ms. Callback `function() {}` of `setTimeout(…)` is queued in Task queue.
3. When promise object is encountered, its callback i.e `function() {}` is queued in Micro task queue.
4. Finally, it executes last `console.log(“four”)` .

**According to standard specification**

1. Once a call stack is emptied, it will check Micro task queue and finds callback `function() {}` of promise.Call stack will execute it **(logs three)**.
2. Once again, call stack is emptied after processing callbacks in Micro task queue. Finally, event loop picks up a new task from the Task queue i.e callback `function() {}` of `setTimeout(…)` **( logs two)** execute it.

---

**Visual Image**

[image: Visual Image]

```js
console.log('one');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('two');
}, 0);
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('three');
})
console.log('four');
```

Comment: dude your answer went above and beyond to explain this and honestly I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the JS call stack; both `setTimeout` and `Promise.resolve().then` are asynchronous calls.

`setTimeout(function(){...}, 0)` simply queues the code to run once the current call stack is finished executing, exactly the same as `Promise.resolve().then()` (albeit to a subqueue). The subqueue finishes executing hence why `three` appears before `two`, and then the main queue is finished, so `setTimeout` can now be called.

Comment: This is simply wrong, and also would not explain the output. `Promise.resolve().then()` is exactly **not** in the same queue as `setTimeout`.

Comment: 1. What's specifically incorrect? 2. I'm not suggesting they're both the same in terms of functionality. I'm saying that they're both async calls that execute once the current call stack is finished. Check the spec...

Comment: @ASDFGerte *A Promise in the pending status. The handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) then gets called asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty)*

Comment: Switching the order of the `setTimeout` and `.then` in the code will **not** change the output order. They are different queues, and not "exactly the same".

Comment: Perhaps the edited answer adds more explanation; I was trying to keep things simple for the OP, but to claim that it's *simply wrong* isn't true at all.

Comment: The way i understand "exactly the same" (not "similar to" or "like") made me write that. The question is primarily about the order of the output, and if `setTimeout` and `.then` behaved "exactly the same", that would not explain the resulting output. Therefore, imho, the edit was necessary, but also solved the issue :)

Comment: Okay, fair enough -- perhaps I was too quick to think the answer through (pre-edit).

Comment: Promise.resolve queues what's called a microtask which is called just after the end of the execution of the current execution block. setTimeout on the other hand schedules a task which has less priority than microtasks. Both are async. and are queued for later execution, but microtasks take priority.